# Images not visible through smartphone

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

www.michaelpeyron.com/wp

That's a demo of a site i'm working on. Whenever I visit it in browser and I reduce the window to smartphone size all images are there. But when I use my iphone 6 and visit the site, the images of instagram, twitter and facebook just isn't there.
I've zero clues about what the reason can be behind this behavior.

The twitter, facebook and instagram images are all from: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome in a PC and I see strange characters instead the social logos. Have you added the font awesome library?

Comment: Woah. Do I now feel stupid right now. I was absolute 100% sure I had linked it. Thanks mate! That solved it!